# Determining a good steel bar for spit roast

Tags: steel

I'm preparing to build a spit roast in my back yard in preparation for a lamb roast party in the future. I have next to no experience working with metals of any kind, and as the steel rods/pipes I'm looking into are quite expensive I want to make sure I'm going to buy something that's gonna support the lamb.

Based on my research I'm thinking a stainless steel 304/316 rod at 7/8" diameter, 6 feet long (it will sit on its supports at a distance of about 6-8 inches inside) should be able to hold at the most a 50-70 pound lamb distributed as evenly as possibly, with makeshift counterweights and balances attached.

However, if this party is a success I'll buy something bigger like a hog or maybe even half a cow in the future.

So my questions are:

- Can 7/8" (or even 1", it's within the budget) diameter, 6 foot rod hold a 50-70 lamb for several hours?
- Can the same diameter hold something weighing up to twice that weight for several hours?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How expensive is the raw material you're looking at? Because you can get commercially made spits for like 100 that would do the job

Comment: Really why are you not getting a party-que or similar?

Comment: From what I've seen I can get a 7/8" x 6 feet SS rod for about 70-80 dollars. Why not just buy a party-que? Because I have all the other materials I would need to build it on hand, besides the spit. No point spending all that money on what is essentially a rod on some supports.

Comment: @whatsisname isn't this the **DIY** stack?

Comment: On the whole, a reasonably thick-walled tube/pipe will do just as well as a solid bar, and a slightly larger diameter tube will do better than a smaller solid bar. The material in the middle does relatively little, structurally. How that compares on price is down to your shopping...

Comment: @Ecnerwal I think I'm going to go ahead with a SCH 40 SS pipe of appropriate thickness. Helps because I can drill holes thru it and drive sharpened rebar spikes thru the animal and the pipe to secure it. Live in the north east so I have a lot of metal manufacturers nearby I can contact. Thanks.

Comment: Just remember (or learn) that when drilling stainless, you want to push hard - if you go lightly, you'll work-harden the stainless until you can't drill it. You want to see nice healthy chips/shavings coming off while drilling. Lubrication is also helpful (use something food-grade for that, here.)

Comment: If you use rebar crossbars you'll need to figure out a way to keep the carcass from sliding along them.  I suppose you could use hose clamps with washers or something.  I used threaded rod with washes and nuts.

Answer (score 4):

Having actually done DIY spit roasting with lambs and pigs (maybe 3 of each?), there's nothing wrong with stainless steel.  I actually started out using a 1" ID black iron pipe from Home Depot, rolling on some rubber rollers.  (I upgraded to a stainless steel round tube for the last beast roast I did; unfortunately I don't seem to have any pics from that.)

I jury-rigged a gear reduction motor up with a bike chain and gears, using a 1/2" socket swivel bolted through the end of the pipe.  I used stainless threaded rods through the pipe with some big washers to keep the carcass in place.  I had a flange on the opposite end of the pipe to which I screwed a piece of wood as a balance weight (spitting the beast mouth-to-tail isn't evenly balanced).

V1.0 of the setup used a bicycle wheel bolted to the end of the pipe, with a peg on a board.  The peg stuck through the spokes to keep the spit in position, and the wheel was manually repositioned and re-pegged every few minutes.  The intensely manual nature of this setup (hours upon hours of repositioning the wheel and waiting) is what prompted V2.0 with the gearmotor.

[image: mechanism]
[image: roasting]
[image: meat]
Cows are probably a different story.  Not sure I'd recommend a whole cow, unless you're feeding an ass ton of people (and have a crap ton of time to do it).  FWIW the first pig I did was over 120 lb and the pipe handled it just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I used a copper pipe with a second internally for a lamb.

I made a couple of spikes and used jubilee clips to hold them. The copper pipe had 2 elbows to give a handle for rotating purposes - a nice chair, 3 guys and cans of beer works well for variable speeds…

If I was to do this for a cow, then I have a 1.25" diameter steel peeler bar nearly 6' long that would do a good job.

I suggest you test before you commit.

Edit:
Just so you know, I used best quality Welsh lamb that was traceable... Oh and it was stuffed with couscous and peppers onions etc so that absorbed much of the cooking juices :)

Comment: What prevents the meat from rotating around the spit instead of with the spit?

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg jubilee clips can work…